# Managing %SYS.PTools.SQLStats data

Tags: profiling, intersystems-cache

I need to profile an application using Caché database and I'm trying to use [CacheMonitor](http://www.cachemonitor.de/) for that.

I have enabled query statistics (I suppose CacheMonitor executes `DO SetSQLStats^%apiSQL(3)` internally) and two days after, my server has gone out of disk space. I'm afraid there is too much data in `%SYS.PTools.SQLQuery` and `%SYS.PTools.SQLStats` and I would like to free some space.

Is there any administration tool to manage these data? How can I delete data from sql statistics?

NOTE: My knowledge about Caché is almost none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is a pretty general problem of how to delete a global and then reclaim the disk space.

To delete the data, you should be able to use a SQL delete statement to clear out %SYS.PTools.SQLStats (which should be larger), and/or %SYS.PTools.SQLQuery.

Since this is Cache, you also might kill the global from the command line.  I haven't used these classes, but looking at the class definition in ^oddDEF it appears to store the data in ^%SYS.PTools.SQLQueryD, ^%SYS.PTools.SQLQueryI, and ^%SYS.PTools.SQLQueryS (which is the standard default storage, so this would be likely anyway).

If you only want to delete some of it you will need to craft your own SQL for it.

Once they are deleted, you need to actually shrink the database (like most databases, it can grow dynamically but doesn't automatically give up any space).  See [this reference](http://docs.intersystems.com/documentation/cache/cache52/PDFS/AGBC_Gblockcopy.pdf) for an example of one way to do that.  The basic idea is on page 3 - you can make a new database then copy all the data into it, then delete the old once you are sure you don't need it.  Don't forget to do a backup first.

To make this easier in the future, you can use the global mapping feature to save the %SYS.PTools globals into their own, new, database.  Then when you want to shrink that database you can just replace it with a new one without copying all the data around (as is suggested in the class documentation for %SYS.PTools.SQLStats).